# Rendering to a multi-planar VkImage

Tags: vulkan

I'd like to use Vulkan to draw to a multi-planar VkImage (I know this is a corner case, but I'm rendering offscreen and passing the image to a video encoder). I can create a `VK_FORMAT_G8_B8_R8_3PLANE_420_UNORM` image, but trying to use it as a color attachment throws all sorts of validation errors which boil down to it being intended for sampling, not rendering, for example:

> format VK_FORMAT_G8_B8_R8_3PLANE_420_UNORM with tiling VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR does not support usage that includes VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT

I have a hunch that I could create 3 different `VkImageView`s, or maybe 3 different `VkImage`s, one for each plane, and attach them all when rendering. Is that the right approach, or is there a better way to achieve what I'm after?